# oracle error code handling cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying to accessing Oracle from Python using cx_ORacle.

I have a select statement that returns no rows ie; NO_DATA_FOUND..and this is how Im handling the error condition.

When I execute this piece of code, the error NO_DATA_FOUND is not catched by the cx_oracle.error or cx_oracle.Databaseerror or cx_oracle.Warning..

How do I handle the NO_DATA_FOUND condition?

code.py

```
def DetermineNames(self): 
    sql = """select NAME from EMP_TAB where fd_fle_id = %s"""%(self.fileid)
    try:
         self.cursor.execute(sql)
         result = self.cursor.fetchall()
         for row in result:
               print('row',row)
    except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
        print("Error:Unable to determine the RAW_OBJ_NAME: Object Name:%s, Function Name:%s  Error:%s")%(self.__class__.__name__,sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
        str(e).strip())                        
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        print("Error:Unable to determine the RAW_OBJ_NAME: Object Name:%s, Function Name:%s  Error:%s")%(self.__class__.__name__,sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
        str(e).strip())
    except cx_Oracle.Warning as e:
        print("Error:Unable to determine the RAW_OBJ_NAME: Object Name:%s, Function Name:%s  Error:%s")%(self.__class__.__name__,sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
        str(e).strip())                     
    return self.rawname
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error condition, which is probably why none of your exceptions are being triggered. Try something like this instead:

```
if not self.cursor.rowcount:
   print 'No rows returned'
```

Comment: Thanks...Is there any way to check the error codes after executing  each sql statements?..

Answer (score 1):

May be use `cx_Oracle._Error.code` and if the value is `1403` then its a `NO DATA FOUND`.

```
....
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
   error, = e.args
   if error.code == 1403:
       print "No rows returned. Error Code:", error.code  
....
```

Comment: when I print-cx_Oracle._Error.code..It shows me a object but not the actual code.

Comment: Well you are correct and in-correct at the same time. `ORA-01403` is a valid Oracle error code which will only occur if you try to fetch a cursor (which returns no records) into a variable (this is handled in Oracle world using `CURSOR%NOTFOUND` known as cursor attributes). If you are not fetching a cursor `INTO` anything (which is highly unlikely), then its not considered an error. In your code, you are fetching the cursor into `result` using `fetchall()` which is destined to give `ORA-01403` if there are no rows to return.